# How to rewrite to a different domain and same URL by using rack-rewrite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rack

I want to make a rewrite to another domain and URL browser will show not be changed.

```
config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Runtime, Rack::Rewrite) do
    r301 %r{/example(.*)}, 'https://example.com$1'
end
```

Now I write above and URL browser show is changed.
How can I resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your DNS configuration. The easiest way would be to create a CNAME record: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record